# É possível preencher uma lista de arvore de forma inversa utilizando stream?

Tags: java, array, java-8, stream, árvore-binária

A questão é o seguinte

Minha classe

```
public class Node{

    private String name;

    private Node parent;

    private List<Node> children;

    public Node() {
    }

    public Node(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Node getParent() {
        return parent;
    }

    public void setParent(Node parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public List<Node> getChildren() {
        return children;
    }

    public void setChildren(List<Node> children) {
        this.children = children;
    }

}
```

Achei vários exemplos para criar uma lista de arvore utilizando stream, 
mas o que preciso é criar uma lista só de 'parents'
Exemplo:

Eu tenho a seguinte hierarquia:

```
1
 1.1
  1.1.1
   1.1.1.1
   1.1.1.2
   1.1.1.3
```

O que preciso é o seguinte:

Vou fazer uma consulta nessa arvore, eu passo como paramentro o node 1.1.1.3,
eu quero uma lista com ele mesmo e seus pais

```
[1.1.1.3, 1.1.1, 1.1, 1]
```

Consegui fazer utilizando uma lista global e preenchendo ela com um método recursivo, mas queria saber se tem uma forma mais elegante de se fazer. Eu li sobre streams do java 8, mas não tenho certeza se atende da forma que preciso.

Alguma ideia?

Obrigado!